# CSS being read by jQuery is not corresponding to CSS being set by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On button press, I want to change the color and background color of a button based on whether or not is "checked" which I'm currently checking by reading the current color.

Currently, it doesn't seem like the CSS value that is being read by jQuery is being updated by the function that jQuery uses to update the CSS.

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3197r2yf/)**

```js
function toggleButton(button) {
  let css = {
    "checked": {
      "background-color": "#609",
      "color": "#fff"
    },
    "unchecked": {
      "background-color": "#ccc",
      "color": "#222"
    }
  }
  button.css("color", "#222") ?
    button.css(css.checked) :
    button.css(css.unchecked)
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleButton($(this))">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This `button.css("color", "#222")` does not magically check the current  `color` value against `"#222"` and returns `true`/`false`: [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Comment: Based on what @Andreas said, that isn't the right way to check the color of an element: https://jsfiddle.net/3197r2yf/1/

Comment: @Andreas Wow I feel stupid. Not sure how I ended up thinking that's what it was doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're using the *setter* of `css()` in your if condition. As this returns a jQuery object it will always equate to true.

The second problem is that even when corrected (`button.css('color') == '#222'`) the `css()` method will return the color in RGB format, so comparing it to the hex value will always be `false`.

To fix the problem, toggle a class on the element instead. It would also be much better practice to use an unobtrusive event handler instead of the outdated `on*` event handler. This has the added benefit of de-coupling the CSS and JS code. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #222;
}

button.foo {
  background-color: #609;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```